# C++ Different compilation error with gcc and visual studio, 'within this context'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, gcc, compiler-errors

I've posted a similar question before but I had a slight mistake in the code so it was disregarded, let me ask again.

In Gcc I get the exact line of compilation error
In VS2010/2012 I have no Idea where the compilation error is, can anyone help?
** In VS how was I supposed to know what line invoked it?

I have the following code:

```
#include "ObjectHolder.h"

int main()
{
    ObjectHolder first(1);
    ObjectHolder second(first);
    return 0;
}
#ifndef NonCopyableObject_Included
#define NonCopyableObject_Included

class NonCopyableObject 
{
    public:
        virtual ~NonCopyableObject () {}

        NonCopyableObject(int i) { m_index = i;}
        int m_index;
        private:
        NonCopyableObject(const NonCopyableObject& other) {}
};
#endif

#ifndef ObjectHolder_Included
#define ObjectHolder_Included
#include "NonCopyableObject.h"

class ObjectHolder 
{
    public:
        virtual ~ObjectHolder ();
        ObjectHolder(int i) : obj(i) {}

        NonCopyableObject obj;
};
#endif
```

VS Error:

```
1>d:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\tester\tester\objectholder.h(13): 

     error C2248: 'NonCopyableObject::NonCopyableObject' : cannot access private member declared in   class 'NonCopyableObject'
               d:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\tester\tester  
     \noncopyableobject.h(13) : see declaration of 'NonCopyableObject::NonCopyableObject'
            d:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\tester\tester
     \noncopyableobject.h(6) : see declaration of 'NonCopyableObject'
            This diagnostic occurred in the compiler generated function    
     'ObjectHolder::ObjectHolder(const ObjectHolder &)'
```

GCC:

```
$ g++ -Wall -Werror --std=c++0x main.cpp -o test_no_copy
In file included from main.cpp:2:0:

     NonCopyableObject.h: In copy constructor `ObjectHolder::ObjectHolder(const ObjectHolder&)':
     NonCopyableObject.h:13:3: error: `NonCopyableObject::NonCopyableObject(const NonCopyableObject&)' is private
     ObjectHolder.h:7:1: error: within this context
     main.cpp: In function `int main()':
     main.cpp:8:27: note: synthesized method `ObjectHolder::ObjectHolder(const ObjectHolder&)' first required here
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to copy an `ObjectHoder`

```
ObjectHolder second(first);
```

But it contains a non-copyable object, so it cannot be copied. You are trying to do something your code is designed to disallow at compilation time. Both compilers are telling you this.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler cannot generate (synthesize) a copy-constructor in `ObjectHolder` because it contains an object of class `NonCopyableObject` which has a private copy-contructor.

By default the generated copy-constructor is invoking the copy-constructor of all member- and parent objects.

Comment: That is not the question, the question is why visual studio doesn't cope and show me the actual line that invoked it

Comment: @Alon: Because the actual line is in generated code, and not human-readable.

Answer (score 1):

It's a great idea to compile using different compilers, as errors can vary tremendously between them and one of them is likely to be more helpful than another. In most cases, I have found [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/)'s error reporting to be best. In your example:

> ```
> source.cpp:9:48: error: unused parameter 'other' [-Werror,-Wunused-parameter]
>     NonCopyableObject(const NonCopyableObject& other) {}
>                                                ^
> source.cpp:25:18: error: call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'ObjectHolder'
>     ObjectHolder second(first);
>                  ^      ~~~~~
> source.cpp:18:23: note: copy constructor of 'ObjectHolder' is implicitly deleted because field 'obj' has an inaccessible copy constructor
>     NonCopyableObject obj;
> ```

[See it here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/2ns87O%241).

Comment: The question is not why the compilation error exist, it is why visual studio doesn't show me the line that actually generates it

Comment: Unfortunately, nobody other than the compiler's implementation team can answer why you get (or don't get) a specific message. I advise you to keep doing what you are and compile with multiple compilers. I've eradicated several bugs from legacy code this way.